# Custom Menus in Google Slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I'm trying to add a custom menu in my presentation, following instructions given on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus. This site says "Apps Script can add new menus in Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, or Forms...". However, when I run the following script, this error message prompts: "**Exception: Cannot call SlidesApp.getUi() from this context. (line 3, file "Code")**". What's wrong?

```
1    function onOpen(){
2      
3      var ui = SlidesApp.getUi();
4      
5      ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
6        .addItem('First item', 'menuItem1')
7        .addToUi();
8    }
```

Comment: It works for me.  Where are you trying to run it from?  The menu doesn't run during the presentation.

Comment: Now it worked!? I'm running from Google Chrome from a business account. Still can't say what the problem was. Anyway... thanks, Cooper!